# Android - Steps to create a kernel level function and expose that to higher Java levels

Tags: android, linux, kernel, gpio

Goal is essentially to provide certain methods that control GPIO outputs eg. Turn an LED on and off and then implement those methods, probably several in a ContentProvider.

This would allow various apps to access the ContentProvider and when certain actions are triggred that would typically insert or return data, a GPIO operation could be performed. I believe this part is ok, it is just getting to the point where you can from the Java level call a kernel level function.

Is it possible? Is it just not worth the hassle? Ideally would like to share low level GPIO functionality between apps and allow another party to develop an app themselves but be able to use these GPIO interacting functions.

Is this achievable? If so, any pointers on how to go about it?

Cheers

Comment: Can you already access the GPIOs via system calls?  If so, you can use the native development kit (NDK) to expose this functionality to the Java layer.  If not, there is a more involved way to achieve this.

Comment: Getting an Android capable ARM micro along with a Texas Instruments development kit. So we have no choice but to map certain GPIO pins to hardware functions. To be honest, really not sure how to go about that either. I was under the impression the NDK just allowed you to use C/C++ for reusability and performance. You are saying the NDK allows lower level control at the kernel level? So not yet, we don't have the equipment yet but have a team of engineers and a deadline to meet.

Comment: The NDK allows you to access what is available in user space and expose it to your app.  If something is not yet exposed via the kernel, then you would have to design a driver for it.  Might be a better way to do this, but you can download the entire Android tree and try building an image for your device.  See if it loads without modification first.  If it does, then you can build your driver on top of it.  You will likely also need a native component to access your driver.  Note that this approach is very platform-specific and not portable.